# limitinternalrecursion wordpress permalinks

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have an NGINX server that is proxy_pass-ing any urls that end in /blog to an IP address where I have a WordPress instance running with Apache.

The issue I am having is that when I enable permalinks I get a LimitInternalRecursion error.  When I don't enable permalinks everything works as expected and I can access all of my blog pages through the proxy.

Here are the contents of the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I found out the rewrite rule provided by WordPress needed to be changed to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
 </IfModule>
```